# Can I use multiple @throws tags for the same exception in Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc, throws

Can I use multiple `@throws` javadoc tags if my application throws the same exception for multiple reasons? For example:

```
@throws UserException if issue 1 happened
@throws UserException if issue 2 happened
@throws UserException if issue 3 happened
```

Is it prohibited by JavaDoc standard?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is valid in java 6,7 and 8. See the docs:

- [Javadoc 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#throws)
- [Javadoc 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@throws)
- [Javadoc 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDCHAHD)

> Multiple @throws tags can be used in a given doc comment **for the same** or different exceptions.

(emph. mine)

Comment: [Java 6 Javadoc Tool doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@throws)

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this the generated JavaDoc contains all 3 @throws.